# Android TabActivity and setContent(int idView) ---> RuntimeException

Tags: android

I have created this little testcase:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            TabSpec spec;
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.service));
        spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.service));
        spec.setContent(R.id.first_tab);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

and this is the relative layout document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/first_tab">

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/serviceButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/service_on" android:textOff="@string/service_off">
    </ToggleButton>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone know why i get this exception at runtime: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131034112 ?

The code seems to be right!

Thanks you for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

You never load your layout in your code (with setContentView()), so any IDs inside your layout will never be found.

Add this line :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.[...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout doesn't have a TabHost element in it. The runtime is looking specifically for a TabHost View with id string "@android:id/tabhost" and it can't find it. I've tried to make a ListActivity without a ListView and come across the same sort of error. See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for an example of a tabbed XML layout.

Comment: if you use TabActivity you can avoid to declare layout.

Comment: Read the first sentence on this page. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html